# PostgreSQL behavior of USING when joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, key

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question so I thought I'd bring it over here to SO.

When joining tables together in PostgreSQL, I often like to use the USING keyword to specify the join condition because it's easier to read at a glance. However, I realized that I don't actually know if this produces different behavior from using the more explicit ON. Are there any performance considerations when choosing between the two?

Finally, how exactly does USING behave when joining more than two tables together? E.g.
`SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (k1) JOIN table3 USING (k2)`
What happens here if table2 has both k1 and k2 vs when table 1 has k1 and k2?

I've played around with the syntax, but it is still unclear to me what exactly is happening. I've searched for documentation about this but have come up empty.

Comment: In terms of performance, there is generally no difference between using USING and ON. The PostgreSQL query planner evaluates both types of joins in the same way. The choice between USING and ON is more about readability and convenience than about performance.

Comment: Could you please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your queries? And the DDL for the tables and indexes involved. The query plan will show you the difference, if there is a difference.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but you could have easily created a test case yourself to discover the behavior. This is part of what SO's guidance to "search, and research" means in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If both `table1` and `table2` have a column `k2`, but they are not used as part of the join condition between `table1` and `table2`, then an exception is raised as demonstrated with the following query:

```
WITH
  table1(id, k1, k2) AS (
    VALUES (11, 11, 21)),
  table2(id, k1, k2) AS (
    VALUES (21, 11, 21)),
  table3(id, k1, k2) AS (
    VALUES (31, 11, 21))
SELECT *
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2
    USING (k1)
  JOIN table3
    USING (k2);
```

```
ERROR:  common column name "k2" appears more than once in left table 

SQL state: 42702
```

The exception occurs because the column reference is ambiguous. This is essentially the same issue that occurs when sorting by a column name that occurs in more than one of the joined tables, but without qualifying the reference.